# Read the first item of a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, fetch

I have a PHP array generated by the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT adresa.Id_Adresa as id FROM adresa";
$result = $this->os->db->conn->query($sql);
$data = array();
while ($r = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $r;
}
```

I want to grab the very first id of this array. How can I do that without parsing all the items? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should add an ORDER BY to your query because the order of data returned is not guarantee without it.

Comment: @Luc M, I do not actually need to order the results. The query I actually use is more difficult and it returns only one id. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT adresa.Id_Adresa as id FROM adresa LIMIT 1";
$result = $this->os->db->conn->query($sql);
$firstId = $result->fetchColumn(0);
```

See the docs at https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Comment: $result->fetchColumn() returned me just what I was needing.Thanks all & especially thanks nickf.

Comment: @Giku Promitt - If this was the answer which solved your problem, you can click the green checkmark (✔) to the left here.

Answer (score 2):

When you say `first id of this array` I am assuming that is the `$data` array, just do:

```
print_r($data[0]);
```

Comment: well, assuming the array does look like [{'id':'1'}], I want to display '1'.

Comment: well then you need to do `echo data[0]->id;`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you limit the number of items returned if you don't need them?

```
$sql = "SELECT adresa.Id_Adresa as id FROM adresa LIMIT 1";
```